# Fetching top n records in pandas pivot , based on multiple criteria and plotting them with matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, pandas, pivot

**Usecase** : Extending the pivot functionality of Pandas. **Fetch top n records & plot them against its own "Click %"(s) vs. no of records of that name**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B','C','A'], 'click':[1,1,0,1,1,0]})
   click name
0      1    A
1      1    A
2      0    B
3      1    B
4      1    C
5      0    A

[6 rows x 2 columns]

#fraction of records present & clicks as a fraction of it's OWN records present
f=df1.pivot_table(rows='name', aggfunc=[len, np.sum])
f['len']['click']/sum(f['len']['click']) , f['sum']['click']/sum(f['sum']['click'])
(name
A       0.500000
B       0.333333
C       0.166667
Name: click, dtype: float64, name
A       0.50
B       0.25
C       0.25
Name: click, dtype: float64)
```

But to be able to plot them need to store the top n records in an object that is supported by matplotlib. 
I tried storing the

> "top names" A,B, C ..etc by creating dict (output of
>   f['len']['click']/sum(f['len']['click']

) )- and sorted by values - after which I stored the "click %" `[A  -> 0.50, B ->   0.25 , C->  0.25]` also in the same dictionary.

****Since this is clearly an overkill - wondering if there's a more pythonic way to do this  ? ****

I also tried head with groupby clause, but it doesn't give me what I am looking for. I am looking for a dataframe as above 
A       0.500000
    B       0.333333
    C       0.166667
    Name: click, dtype: float64, name
    A       0.50
    B       0.25
    C       0.25
except that the top n logic should be embedded (head(n) does not work with n depends on my data-set - I guess I need to use "apply" ? - and post this the Object , which is a "" object needs to be identified by matplotlib with its own labels (top n "name" here)

**Here's my dict function implementation :- # This is an OVERKILL just to fetch top n by a custom criteria as above**

```
def freq_counts(df_var,n): # df_var is like df1.name , just to make the top n logic generic for each column name
    perct_freq=dict((df_var.value_counts()*100)/len(df_var))
    vec=[]
    for key,value in perct_freq.items():
        if value>=n :
            vec.append([key,value])
    return vec
freq_counts(df1.name,3) # eg. top 3 freq counts - to get the names, see vec[i][0] which has the corresponding keys
#In this example when I calculate the "perct_freq", which is a Series object, I would ideally want to avoid converting this to a dict - What an overkill !
```

1. Store the actual occurances (len of names) , and find the fraction of a "name" in population
2. Against this, also fins the "sucess outcome" and find it as a fraction of its OWN population
3. Finally plot top n name(s), output of (1) & (2) in same plot - criteria for top n should be based on (1) as a percentage 
   Ie. for (1) & (2) use dataframes that support plot with 
   name as labels in x axis
   (1) as y axis (primary)
   (2) as y axis (secondary)

> PPS:  In the code above - 
>   (1) is  > f['len']['click']/sum(f['len']['click'])    and
>    (2) is  > f['sum']['click']/sum(f['sum']['click'])

Comment: Have you tried (f.astype('float')/f.sum()).sort(['len', 'sum'], ascending=False)[:3]

Comment: @user1827356  After I run "=df1.pivot_table(rows='name', aggfunc=[len, np.sum]) and then your command this gives "ValueError: Cannot sort by duplicate column len" .After I remove "len" this gives, "% str(by))
ValueError: Cannot sort by duplicate column sum" btw- why are we typecasting "f" to float ?

Comment: 1. The reason for the error is that pandas is not handling multi-index columns well. You can get around it by doing this before the sort - f.columns = f.columns.levels[0]
2. If you don't type cast to 'float', division returns 0 instead of fraction (integer div)